# How can I get a remote village transportation network from openstreetmap?

Tags: openstreetmap, filter, transportation, feature-extraction

How can I get such a remote village transportation network from [openstreetmap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)?

- nodes represent remote villages
- links represents public transportation tools, like buses

Something like that:

[image]

It is reasonable to regard bus stations as villages or towns. But how can I extract those info?

Should I create a map firstly as described in [Openptmap/Installation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Openptmap/Installation) (it is too complicate for me) and then filter public transportations?

Comment: Qgis has a nice feature to extract OSM data, quite easily. What software do you use?

Comment: @dof1985 Thx. I extract those data for my simulation, [The ONE simulator](http://www.netlab.tkk.fi/tutkimus/dtn/theone/). What I need is only nodes and links, and then convert it into wkt format.

Comment: than I suggest you try qgis, its free and easy. Here is a link to a [tutorial relating to OSM data](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/downloading_osm_data.html)

Comment: So are you trying to extract OSM data so that you can input it in the simulator package you're using? if that's the case, can you provide a data format required for the data to be in?